# gojs and Aurelia mismatch error

Tags: aurelia, gojs

I created a new aurelia project and installed gojs via npm. I added gojs to the aurelia.json dependencies and, without adding any gojs code, just tried to build the project. The build worked fine and gojs went to the vendor-bundle.js The issue is, when I run the project, I get an error from gojs. When I remove the gojs dependency in aurelia.json, the project runs just fine but adding it back always throws the same error located below. Please help.

```
Uncaught Error: Mismatched anonymous define() module: [object Object]
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#mismatch
   at makeError (vendor-bundle.js:11531)
   at intakeDefines (vendor-bundle.js:12617)
   at vendor-bundle.js:12815
makeError @ vendor-bundle.js:11531
intakeDefines @ vendor-bundle.js:12617
(anonymous) @ vendor-bundle.js:12815
setTimeout (async)
req.nextTick @ vendor-bundle.js:13178
localRequire @ vendor-bundle.js:12812
requirejs @ vendor-bundle.js:13160
(anonymous) @ vendor-bundle.js:13199
(anonymous) @ vendor-bundle.js:13508
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To clear up some confusion here, you're talking about declaring the dependency in aurelia.json which implies you're using aurelia-cli in conjunction with the **requirejs** loader.

jmdavid's answer mentions **webpack** which is a different beast altogether. You don't declare dependencies in aurelia.json there; webpack resolves those by itself via the imports it finds in your entry file. I would actually recommend switching to webpack for various reasons; the fact that it would fix the error is just one of them.

The error is likely caused by the `go.js` module being loaded *twice*. The error throws on the second load; it should still work regardless of the error. You can't make the error go away in any straightforward manner with requirejs, this is due to how the `go.js` release is packed.

The only error-free way to load `go.js` here would be to do so *before requirejs is loaded*.  In aurelia.json:

```
"node_modules/gojs/release/go.js",
"node_modules/requirejs/require.js"
```

And no need to import it then either, it will just be available globally.

Comment: This worked great. Thanks for explaining what the error was.

Comment: Any idea why the gojs module would be loaded twice? Is this a bug in the go.js library?

Comment: @SimonSarris Since you're a go.js dev, I took a look and found that it actually chokes straight away on this bit: `(window.go = ca, window.define(ca));`. It's not being defined twice; rather, it's being set globally once, and attempted to be defined but that call simply fails. You need to remove that `window.ca = ca` because it beats the purpose of asynchronous module loading and change the define call to `window.define('go', ca)`. That will allow people to do something like `import * as go from "go"` and it won't be loaded until *that* call happens in the user's code.

Comment: Actually the script will be loaded anyway because, well, the library's release format just isn't module-loader friendly. If this is something you're looking to improve, I recommend you take a look at any of aurelia's core packages and look at the `dist` folders. A separate release file per module loader format, all automatically generated. It's neat and it's something I think is a shame libraries like go.js and gsap don't do it that way.

Comment: @FredKleuver Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 2):

Probably the versions are oudated on fedoranimus github (https://github.com/fedoranimus/aurelia-gojs).

I made it work by creating a new project with the cli (au new) with webpack and typescript, then npm installed gojs (version "^1.8.15"), then copied relevant code from fedoranimus.

Comment: I created a new project (au new) and npm installed gojs, added gojs to the aurelia.json and au build and the error still happens.  Did you add gojs to the aurelia.json file?

Comment: @jmdavid he didn't mention fedoranimus' github anywhere so I don't even think that's relevant here. The versions make no difference either

Comment: Looks like using webpack was the difference between your version and mine. I use requirejs and that was where the issue originates. Doing what @FredKleuver said solved the issue.

Comment: FYI: The dependencies have been updated. But yes, OP was seeing an issue with requirejs. Hopefully the GoJS team will give us a named define in a future release.